# In protractor, how do I check if a table cell contains particular text?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing, angular9

I'm trying to debug an e2e test using Selenium webdriver manager v 12.1.7 with protractor 5.4.3.  I want to see if a table cell is present on my page that has certain text.  I'm trying the below

```
const elements = await element.all(by.css(cellSelector));
console.log("cell selector:" + cellSelector);
for (const elem of elements) {
  console.log("elem:" + elem.getAttribute('innerHTML'));
  console.log("comparing " + elem.innerHTML + " with " + cellValue);
  if (elem.innerHTML === cellValue) {
    return true;
```

However, even though I can see the loop repeating, the value of

```
elem.getAttribute('innerHTML')
```

is always returned as

```
[object Object]
```

and the value of

```
elem.innerHTML
```

is returned as

```
undefined
```

What's the right way to see if a table cell contains certain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because `elem.getAttribute('innerHTML')` returns Promise. And everything that returns a promise needs to be resolved.

One way, is `.then` syntax, see an example below, but then erase it from your memory and never use :)

```
elem.getAttribute('innerHTML').then(result => console.log(result))
```

another way, which demonstrated to be at least 1000 times better is `async/await`

```
let result = await elem.getAttribute('innerHTML');
console.log(result);
```

But when you go with `await`, you need the wrapping function to be declared as asynchronous. So likely you want to do something like this

```
describe(`describe`, () => {
    it('it block', async () => { // <-------------- see this async?
        let result = await elem.getAttribute('innerHTML');
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

PS

The reason your `elem.innerHTML` doesn't work because you think of it as webElement whereas this is ElementFinder which doesn't have a property `innerHTML` and thus is `undefined`

If you still want to go with this, you can inject this code into the browser's console, where all elements are available as webElements

```
let text = await browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].innerHTML', elem.getWebElement());
console.log(text)
```

But you still have to resolve the promise